# enable dropdown when checkbox is checked in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

i want to disable dropdown when user uncheck the checkbox. It should be pretty Simple but my code is not working... My code is :-

```
<div>
    @Html.CheckBox("Use_Favicon_Image", true, new { id= "1" })
    <label for="Use_Favicon_Image">Want to Use favicon</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <p>Select Favicon Image </p>
      @Html.DropDownList("FaviconImage", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "1.jpg" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2.jpg" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "3.jpg" }, }, new { id = "2" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                // disable the dropdown:
                $('#2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#2').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: are you experiencing some error? I've tried your code and it works, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vbnemm5/)

Comment: Yes, it works fine and inspect and check any errors are here in browser.

Comment: isn't it browser specific? maybe try prop instead of attribute, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vbnemm5/1/)

Comment: may be OP wanted it in reverse way? as per the message given for the check box. I am just guessing

Comment: I mean its not working. Whether i check the checkbox or not , nature of dropdown remains same i.e dropdown still showing all the fields.

Comment: Not browser specific. Just to check if any errors are there because of jQuery version.

Comment: Its working now.There were some JQuery version problems. Thanks for the Answers.

Comment: @BilalHussain. Please delete the question. It cannot be reproduced and is of no value to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function () {
        $('#1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                // disable the dropdown:
                $('#2').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('#2').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#1').change(function () {
        $('#2').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'))                
    });
});
```